# Using JsonPath in Java (8) to create/add nodes and arrays

Tags: java, jsonpath, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am trying to create or update a JSON with a new key:value nodes inside a JsonArray.
So far I am able to add simple values using a map of  nodes, but I am unable to add an array.

The goal is to create a JSON string with the following values:

```
{
    "curfew": [{
        "enabled": true,
        "lock_time": "00:00",
        "unlock_time": "00:10"
    },
    {
        "enabled": true,
        "lock_time": "00:20",
        "unlock_time": "00:30"
    }]
}
```

Starting from a new and empty JSON and later adding more values (such as the second "curfew" array).

```
Map<String, Object> values = ImmutableMap.of(
                                    "enabled", true,
                                    "lock_time", "00:00",
                                    "unlock_time", "00:10");
String emptyJson = "{}"; //empty json
DocumentContext doc = getDocument(emptyJson)
doc.set(JsonPath.compile("$.curfew"), values).jsonString();
```

So far I am getting this (NOT AN ARRAY)

```
{
    "curfew": {
        "enabled": true,
        "lock_time": "00:00",
        "unlock_time": "05:00"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `List<Map<String, Object>>` and then add your map in the list

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(values);
```

And set the list in doc

```
doc.set(JsonPath.compile("$.curfew"), list).jsonString();
```

Comment: I was so close to that solution, but for some reason failed. this totally works! thank you